XmlMapper readValue return object with null value
I receive an Xml like this one from a soap call (I cannot edit the response, I need to work with this):
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="url">
    <soap:Body>
        <myResponse 
        xmlns="url2" 
        Id="responseId"/>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

I got an object in java to map this response
@Data
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "soap:Envelope")
public class MyResponse {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "soap:Body")
    Body body = new Body();

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "xmlns:soap",
            isAttribute = true)
    String soapEnv = "url";

    @Data
    public static class Body {
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "myResponse")
        MyResponse myResponse = new MyResponse();
        @Data
        public static class MyResponse {
            @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "xmlns",
                    isAttribute = true)
            protected String xmlns = "url1";
            @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Id",
                    isAttribute = true)
            protected String responseId;
        }
    }
}

I'm trying to read it like this
var xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.configure(
                            SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS,
                            false);
xmlMapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
xmlMapper.configure(
                            ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION,
                            true);
xmlMapper.configure(
                            DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,
                            false);
try {
    return xmlMapper.readValue(response, MyResponse.class);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

But I get a MyResponse with responseId null (and all other properties except for xmlns, I only wrote responseId here to keep it as simple as possible).
I think there is something wrong with my XmlMapper configuration (maybe because I got my values into the attributes instead of tags, but I get them like that) can you help me fix it?
Thank you.

I think you use the annotation in wrong way.
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="url">

soap - is short name for namespace which is specified with xmlns:soap under url "url".
Envelope is name of the element within namespace "url".
So your POJO should start with annotation :
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Envelope", namespace="url")

Namespace are sometimes confusing, but in your code you must work always with URL/URI. You can for example receive XML which is same, but use different short name for particular namespace. For example this is same XML :
<abcd:Envelope xmlns:abcd="url">
  <abcd:Body>
    <myResponse xmlns="url2" Id="responseId"/>
  </abcd:Body>
</abcd:Envelope>

Radek

Thank you for your answer but I don't think this solve my problem. I can understand that you want to improve my code and I will implement suggestions that will do that and I really thank you for that... but right now the priority is to get MyResponse.responseId with the xml value.

Nevermind I was thinking it was not a response that solved the issue but it actually does. I'm sorry because I didn't understand it before. Thank you. I'm upvoting and accepting this answer now
